# Windows DNS won't start on reboot

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, service

Last night a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine I maintain automatically rebooted after installing updates, without starting the DNS service. Since the machine is the network's DNS server, I got a call in the morning to say the Internet was down.

This has happened several times; I log in, manually start the service, everything is fine. But I can't figure out why this is happening.

The DNS Service is set for Automatic (not disabled), so it's not that.

When I look in the Event Viewer, it doesn't seem like there was even an attempt to start DNS; there are no error messages for DNS.

Any pointers on other events to look for (the logs are so noisy) would be appreciated.

This is a small office LAN, nothing fancy, the server is a DC. I don't believe there is anything unusual about the setup but I'll be happy to provide any additional information that might be relevant.

Comment: Is this a single DC environment?

Comment: @pablo Yes, single DC.

Comment: While not a solution, ensure you have the service set to restart after failure on the Recovery tab.

Comment: what are the DNS servers configured on the DC?

Comment: @pablo The DC has one ethernet connection; the DNS servers are (1) the interface's own IP address and (2) the loopback address (127.0.0.1). I realize that's kind of silly, but I'd get warnings if I didn't have two addresses, even though I don't have two DNS servers.

Comment: @John_Gardeniers Thanks, it's got the default recovery settings (restart the service after the first and second failure, then give up). Since I don't see any evidence that it tried to start even once, I'm not sure changing the settings here would help.

Comment: yeah that might be the problem.  Just as a test try and set the secondary dns to a public one like google at 8.8.8.8.  then reboot the server and see if it comes up normally.

Comment: @pablo The problem with entering a public DNS server (like Google or my ISPs) is that Windows then complains that the DNS server doesn't know anything about the domain's zone (which of course it wouldn't).

Comment: but did it boot up normally?  if that is the case then a few host file entries will get it to start up.

Comment: No, you never want to put public DNS servers in your domain controller's DNS servers list. Those should only go in the unconditional forwarders list for recursive DNS lookups.

Comment: @SturdyErde unless you have a registered dns zone with the dns record of the internal AD controller published, then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the service to delayed start.

Comment: @Vick_Vega Are you sure this is a good idea? A lot of things depend on DNS being available, but the DNS Server service entry doesn't list any explicit dependencies.

Comment: @benzado, Exactly what we need. If a lot of services depend on DNS, meaning they will not start without having DNS up and running. Worth giving a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running DNS on VM's I would spin up a second server, install DNS services and point your servers to the second DNS server as a secondary provider. If the problem persists with the primary DNS server you can retire it. This is assuming you are unable to find a solution to your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Check the recovery tab of the service. Tell it to restart the service at every fail and see if that helps. Other than that it's hard to say without eventlogs. Was this a one time thing, or does it happen at every reboot?

Btw, upgrade! It's end of life in 2 days...

Comment: I have no idea if that server is still running; I left that job many years ago. :-)